# Como realizar um update em um Spinner a partir do dado do EditText no Android

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, sqlite, spinners

Tenho um Spinner que está sendo preenchido com dados do SQLite, quero pegar esses dados, edita-los e atualiza-los

Meu metodo da classe SpinnerDataBase (responsável pela base de dados do Spinner)

```
public void alteraRegistroSpinner (int id, String label){
        ContentValues values;
        String where;

        db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        where = SpinnerDatabase.KEY_ID + "=" +id;

        values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(SpinnerDatabase.KEY_NAME,label);

        db.update(SpinnerDatabase.TABLE_LABELS,values,where,null);
        db.close();
    }
```

Método no meu Fragment que joga o dado do Spinner no EditText

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String passaValor = spinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                editarAssunto.setText(passaValor);

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

Eu preciso chamar dentro do onItemSelectedListener? Como que eu passo os dados novos para o BD?

Comment: Qual a lista ou array que está com os valores do banco de dados ?

Comment: Essa aqui: private void loadSpinnerData (){
        SpinnerDatabase db = new SpinnerDatabase(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        List<String> labels = db.getAllLabels();

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,labels);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }